# How do I inject user so I do not have to look him up in Laravel request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following a tutorial on Laravel signed routes:

https://dev.to/fwartner/laravel-56---user-activation-with-signed-routes--notifications-oaa

To create the signed route author does this:

```
$url = URL::signedRoute('activate-email', ['user' => $this->user->id]);
```

notice that to the 'user' he only assigned the id...

Later when user in question clicks the generated link and another part of code does this:

```
Route::get('/activate-email/{user}', function (Request $request) {
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401, 'This link is not valid.');
    }

    $request->user()->update([
        'is_activated' => true
    ]);

    return 'Your account is now activated!';
})->name('activate-email');
```

I am confused by this part:

```
$request->user()->update([
    'is_activated' => true
]);
```

Author accesses user() directly and runs the update on him?

When I in my own code tried this:

dd($request->user()) I got null and if I tried
dd($request->user) I got user id number.

How is author able to call user()->update without looking up the user. I do not see where he does inject the User object, so it seems like magic to me or perhaps the author did not test his own code fully, which is on GitHub: https://github.com/fwartner/laravel-user-activation

So how do I inject the user into the route so I do not have to explicitly look him up with

```
$user = User::find($request->user);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to inject the user object into the route. You should be able to do everything you want with just the user ID.  A quick and dirty option is this: `DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user)->update(array('is_activated' => true));` Using Eloquent would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `$request->user` and `$request->user()`

`$request->user()` is the same as `auth()->user()`, so it is getting the authenticated user.

The `$request->user` just get the param user in the Request Object.

If you want to get a user directly without making a query to retreive it from the database you have to inject it directly in the route (or method) like this (assuming your user model is User.php):

```
Route::get('/activate-email/{user}', function (User $user, Request $request) {
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401, 'This link is not valid.');
    }

    $request->user()->update([
        'is_activated' => true
    ]);

    return 'Your account is now activated!';
})->name('activate-email');
```

Notice that `$user` match with `{user}` in the Route (this will make automatically model binding)

Answer (score 1):

The `user()` method is defined on the `Request` object. See the api docs:

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_user

If your route is using an auth guard, the user will be bound on each request.

As an alternative, you can always use the `Auth` facade or `auth` helper to access the user:

```
Auth::user()
// or
auth()->user()
```

Comment: Hi Digital, user is not logged in when he/she makes the reuqest, only user id is in the request, can the above still map the id to the user object for me?

Comment: You'll need to use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) in that case. Laravel should handle this by default. A route with `{user}` will resolve to the `User` model, where `{user}` is the id (primary key) of the db record.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I just cant get it working. This http://laraone.oo/backend/activate/7 gives me 404 which means laravel thinks user does not exist, but it does exist in users table with id=7 ....     Route::get('/activate/{user}', function (\App\Models\User $user) {
        dd('we here?');
    });

Comment: Try explicitly binding the model to the route, in your RouteServiceProvider's boot method, add: `Route::model('user', App\Models\User::class);`